# Can a cable be used to connect the official Xbox wireless headset to an Xbox Series controller?

Tags: controllers, hardware, audio-hardware, xbox-series-x-series-s

Can I use a cable to connect an Xbox Wireless Headset (the official one) to the standard Xbox wireless controller? USB-C to 3.5mm TRRS I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [official FAQ page](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/accessories/xbox-wireless-headset-faq) for the headset states it does not support a 3.5mm connection:

> Can I use a wired 3.5mm connection for my Xbox Wireless Headset?
>
> No. The Xbox Wireless Headset provides a reliable wireless connection with no dongles or wires required, and it does not support a 3.5mm connection. However, you can use a USB-C cable to receive audio and power from a connected device. You may need to purchase a longer USB-C cable, though, as the one included with the headset for charging purposes is only 14 inches long.